# How do I get my eloquent model relationships to return results instead of empty array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to query a model to return results when a specific condition is met, I get results if I dont include where clause but once I include where clause I get an empty array, I have checked all the values and they exist in the DB

Model UserProductListMap

```
class UserProductListMap extends UuidModel
{
    protected $table = 'user_product_list_map';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserProduct', 'product_id',             'uuid');
    }

    public function lists()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserShoppingList',   'shopping_list_id', 'uuid');
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public function getUserListMappings($listId, $userId)
{
    try {
       $produc = Models::with('lists')->where('uuid',$listId);
       $data =[];
       foreach ($produc as $products) {
            $data = $products;
       }
       return $data;
        //$result =  $this->getModel()->first();
        //$result = $result->product->name;

    } catch (QueryException $exception) {
        throw new ResourceGetError('Product');
    } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
        throw new ResourceGetError('Product');
    }
}
```

I want to get results from usershoppinglistmap where shopping_list_id = $listId and where user_id = $userId

Comment: What table is the `user_id` on?

Answer (score 1):

You missing the `->get()`

try to update your code as following:

```
public function getUserListMappings($listId, $userId)
{
    try {
       // add the missing ->get()
       $produc = Models::with('lists')->where('uuid',$listId)->get();
       $data =[];
       foreach ($produc as $products) {
            $data = $products;
       }
       return $data;
        //$result =  $this->getModel()->first();
        //$result = $result->product->name;

    } catch (QueryException $exception) {
        throw new ResourceGetError('Product');
    } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
        throw new ResourceGetError('Product');
    }
}
```

Comment: i did but still get an empty array